# EXC_BAD_ACCESS invoking a block

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, objective-c-blocks, nspanel

UPDATE | I've uploaded a sample project using the panel and crashing here: http://w3style.co.uk/~d11wtq/BlocksCrash.tar.gz (I know the "Choose..." button does nothing, I've not implemented it yet).

UPDATE 2 | Just discovered I don't even have to invoke anything on `newFilePanel` in order to cause a crash, I merely need to use it in a statement.

This also causes a crash:

```
[newFilePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[windowController window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    newFilePanel; // Do nothing, just use the variable in an expression
}];
```

It appears the last thing dumped to the console is sometimes this: "Unable to disassemble dyld_stub_objc_msgSend_stret.", and sometimes this: "Cannot access memory at address 0xa".

I've created my own sheet (an NSPanel subclass), that tries to provide an API similar to NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel, in that it presents itself as a sheet and invokes a block when done.

Here's the interface:

```
//
//  EDNewFilePanel.h
//  MojiBaker
//
//  Created by Chris Corbyn on 29/12/10.
//  Copyright 2010 Chris Corbyn. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class EDNewFilePanel;

@interface EDNewFilePanel : NSPanel <NSTextFieldDelegate> {
    BOOL allowsRelativePaths;

    NSTextField *filenameInput;

    NSButton *relativePathSwitch;

    NSTextField *localPathLabel;
    NSTextField *localPathInput;
    NSButton *chooseButton;

    NSButton *createButton;
    NSButton *cancelButton;
}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL allowsRelativePaths;

+(EDNewFilePanel *)newFilePanel;

-(void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)aWindow completionHandler:(void (^)(NSInteger result))handler;
-(void)setFileName:(NSString *)fileName;
-(NSString *)fileName;
-(void)setLocalPath:(NSString *)localPath;
-(NSString *)localPath;
-(BOOL)isRelative;

@end
```

And the key methods inside the implementation:

```
-(void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)aWindow completionHandler:(void (^)(NSInteger result))handler {
    [NSApp beginSheet:self
       modalForWindow:aWindow
        modalDelegate:self
       didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
          contextInfo:(void *)[handler retain]];
}

-(void)dismissSheet:(id)sender {
    [NSApp endSheet:self returnCode:([sender tag] == 1) ? NSOKButton : NSCancelButton];
}

-(void)sheetDidEnd:(NSWindow *)aSheet returnCode:(NSInteger)result contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    ((void (^)(NSUInteger result))contextInfo)(result);
    [self orderOut:self];
    [(void (^)(NSUInteger result))contextInfo release];
}
```

This all works provided my block is just a no-op with an empty body.  My block in invoked when the sheet is dismissed.

```
EDNewFilePanel *newFilePanel = [EDNewFilePanel newFilePanel];
[newFilePanel setAllowsRelativePaths:[self hasSelectedItems]];
[newFilePanel setLocalPath:@"~/"];
[newFilePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[windowController window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    NSLog(@"I got invoked!");
}];
```

But as soon as I try to access the panel from inside the block, I crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  For example, this crashes:

```
EDNewFilePanel *newFilePanel = [EDNewFilePanel newFilePanel];
[newFilePanel setAllowsRelativePaths:[self hasSelectedItems]];
[newFilePanel setLocalPath:@"~/"];
[newFilePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[windowController window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    NSLog(@"I got invoked and the panel is %@!", newFilePanel);
}];
```

It's not clear from the debugger with the cause is.  The first item (zero 0) on the stack just says "??" and there's nothing listed.

The next items (1 and 2) in the stack are the calls to `-endSheet:returnCode:` and `-dismissSheet:` respectively.  Looking through the variables in the debugger, nothing seems amiss/out of scope.

I had thought that maybe the panel had been released (since it's autoreleased), yet even calling `-retain` on it right after creating it doesn't help.

Am I implementing this wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a little odd for you to `retain` a parameter in one method and `release` it in another, when that object is not an instance variable.

I would recommend making the `completionHandler` bit of your `beginSheet` stuff an instance variable.  It's not like you'd be able to display the sheet more than once at a time anyway, and it would be cleaner this way.

Also, your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is most likely coming from the `[handler retain]` call in your `beginSheet:` method.  You're probably invoking this method with something like (for brevity):

```
[myObject doThingWithCompletionHandler:^{ NSLog(@"done!"); }];
```

If that's the case, you *must* `-copy` the block instead of retaining it.  The block, as typed above, lives on the stack.  However, if that stack frame is popped off the execution stack, then that block is gone.  *poof*  Any attempt to access the block later will result in a crash, because you're trying to execute code that no longer exists and has been replaced by garbage.  As such, you must invoke `copy` on the block to move it to the heap, where it can live beyond the lifetime of the stack frame in which it was created.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  Copying solves everything.  Also, thanks for the input regarding where I'm retaining/releasing.  It felt strange even to me, but I was following a pattern somewhere in the apple documentation if I recall correctly (they were retaining and releasing a NSNumber).  A transient ivar is probably less risky.

Comment: Forgot to add, your answer was very clear, it makes sense that you'd have to copy it in order to keep it around in this case since the panel is invoked asynchronously and the stack will of course end.

Comment: I suggest also using Block_copy and Block_release

Answer (score -1):

Try defining your EDNewFilePanel with the `__block` modifier:

```
__block EDNewFilePanel *newFilePanel = [EDNewFilePanel newFilePanel];
```

This should retain the object when the block is called, which may be after the Panel object is released. As an unrelated side-effect, this will make also make it mutable within the block scope.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't make a difference, it still crashes.  Incidentally, NSOpenPanel doesn't require any use of `__block`.  Thanks though (PS: I've added a link to a sample project in the question).

Comment: __block does exactly the opposite of what you described.