# NSOpenPanel crashing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, crash-reports, nsopenpanel

I've got into some serious trouble and it seems like the culprit is... an `NSOpenPanel`.

**My Code is something like :**

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel  = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

[openPanel setPrompt:@"Save Here"];

[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[self thePanel] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH SELECTION
    }
    else {
        //[openPanel close];
    }
}];
```

And here comes the issue (actually, it has NEVER happened to me (under 10.6.8 and 10.8.20), but I have received numerous crash reports from users (almost exclusively running 10.6)).

**Here's the crash report :**

```
Process:         MY_APP_NAME + [1330]
Path:            /Users/Kellys/Desktop/MY_APP_NAME +.app/Contents/MacOS/MY_APP_NAME +
Identifier:      uk.co.insili.MY_APP_NAME
Version:         1.0 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [112]

Date/Time:       2012-10-14 15:51:41.911 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          2449375 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           10
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  3037 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   10
Anonymous UUID:                      AE022341-E3DA-4AF1-9BAD-F960E79D80DF

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000030
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc[1330]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83b669de -[NSImage _allocAuxiliaryStorage] + 158
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83ceaf05 -[NSImage copyWithZone:] + 66
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83fd543c -[NSNavView _setupNormalFileListModeControl] + 154
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83fd5f32 -[NSNavView awakeFromNib] + 204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff835909fd -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 205
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83b6185b -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1445
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83c08d14 -[NSNib instantiateNibWithExternalNameTable:] + 564
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83c08a92 -[NSNib instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 233
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83fd6b07 +[NSNavView navView] + 109
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84044062 -[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout) _initContentView] + 1230
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8403d60b -[NSSavePanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 367
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84041af5 +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 198
12  uk.co.insili.MY_APP_NAME        0x0000000100002d5f 0x100000000 + 11615
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83cf2eda -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 95
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83cf2e39 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 94
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83d7e84b -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1715
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83daf37a -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 555
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83d7d2f5 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 624
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83c973a7 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 5409
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83bccafa -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4719
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83b636de -[NSApplication run] + 474
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff83b5c3b0 NSApplicationMain + 364
22  uk.co.insili.MY_APP_NAME        0x0000000100001404 0x100000000 + 5124

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81749c0a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174badd _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174b7b4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174b2de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174ac08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aaa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aa2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174ae3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aaa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81730d7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff817313ed mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8357d902 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8357cd8f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8357cb16 CFRunLoopRun + 70
5   com.apple.DesktopServices       0x00007fff861c8326 TSystemNotificationTask::SystemNotificationTaskProc(void*) + 514
6   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore  0x00007fff898940d1 PrivateMPEntryPoint + 63
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81769fd6 _pthread_start + 331
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff81769e89 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aa2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174ae3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aaa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aa2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174ae3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aaa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aa2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174ae3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aaa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aa2a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174ae3c _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff8174aaa5 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x3ff0000000000000  rbx: 0x000000010016e970  rcx: 0x00007fff7028d650  rdx: 0x0000000000000018
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000008  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfe7f0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfe7d0
   r8: 0x0000000000000001   r9: 0x000000010016ea30  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000007
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000008  r14: 0x00000002000bc5a0  r15: 0x0000000200044800
  rip: 0x00007fff83b669de  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000030

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x10000efff +uk.co.insili.MY_APP_NAME 1.0 (1) <D849E4F3-593B-3E81-BF47-7E77A1A060FF> /Users/Kellys/Desktop/MY_APP_NAME +.app/Contents/MacOS/MY_APP_NAME +
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <B536F2F1-9DF1-3B6C-1C2C-9075EA219A06> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8008f000 -     0x7fff8008fff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <DA9BFF01-40DF-EBD5-ABB7-787DAF2D77CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff8031a000 -     0x7fff80439fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <14115D29-432B-CF02-6B24-A60CC533A09E> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff80bcf000 -     0x7fff80c5bfef  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <6860DE26-0D42-D1E8-CD7C-5B42D78C1E1D> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff80c5c000 -     0x7fff80c70ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <621B7415-A0B9-07A7-F313-36BEEDD7B132> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff80d1c000 -     0x7fff80e5afff  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251) <32233D4D-00B7-CE14-C881-6BF19FD05A03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff80e90000 -     0x7fff8122dfe7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.37) <16DFF6CD-EA58-CE62-A1D7-5F6CE3D066DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff8122e000 -     0x7fff81277fef  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <B0F4CA55-445F-E901-0FCF-47B3B4BAE6E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff81730000 -     0x7fff818f1fef  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8192c000 -     0x7fff819a9fef  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <35ECA411-2C08-FD7D-11B1-1B7A04921A5C> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff82a15000 -     0x7fff82a1bfff  libCGXCoreImage.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <D2F8C7E3-CBA1-2E66-1376-04AA839DABBB> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXCoreImage.A.dylib
    0x7fff82a2e000 -     0x7fff82adefff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11) <085D80F5-C9DC-E252-C21B-03295E660C91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff82ee6000 -     0x7fff82f07fff  libresolv.9.dylib 41.1.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9410EC7F-4D24-6740-AFEE-90405750FAD7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff82f46000 -     0x7fff82f55fff  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <7CCBD70E-BF31-A7A7-DB98-230687773145> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff82f56000 -     0x7fff831dfff7  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002) <772E1B13-8271-02F8-B1FE-023592A7AED7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff8325e000 -     0x7fff83281fff  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6) <42FA5783-EB80-1168-4015-B8C68F55842F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff83282000 -     0x7fff8339cfff  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <D1650AED-02EF-EFB3-100E-064C7F018745> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
    0x7fff8339d000 -     0x7fff833dbfe7  libFontRegistry.dylib ??? (???) <395D7C0D-36B5-B353-0DC8-51ABC0B1C030> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff833dc000 -     0x7fff83428fff  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <F7221B46-DC4F-3153-CE61-7F52C8C293CF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff83429000 -     0x7fff83442fff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <CCF79716-7CC6-2520-C6EB-A4F56AD0A207> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff83443000 -     0x7fff834e3fff  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <B90B7C31-FEF8-3C26-BFB3-D8A48BD2C0DA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff834e4000 -     0x7fff834f6fe7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <76B83C8D-8EFE-4467-0F75-275648AFED97> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff8352f000 -     0x7fff83530fff  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <EA4D1607-2BD5-2EE2-2A3B-632EEE5A444D> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff83531000 -     0x7fff836a8fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.6 (550.44) <BB4E5158-E47A-39D3-2561-96CB49FA82D4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff837af000 -     0x7fff837b4fff  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <5B2AF093-1E28-F0CF-2C13-BA9AB4E2E177> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff837b5000 -     0x7fff837bafff  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <6BBC351E-40B3-F4EB-2F35-05BDE52AF87E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff837bb000 -     0x7fff837bbff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <10A0B9E9-4988-03D4-FC56-DDE231A02C63> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff837f7000 -     0x7fff838cbfe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4 (454.12.4) <C83E2BA1-1818-B3E8-5334-860AD21D1C80> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff8393c000 -     0x7fff83940ff7  libCGXType.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <DB710299-B4D9-3714-66F7-5D2964DE585B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
    0x7fff83941000 -     0x7fff83997fe7  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <9BC0CAD5-47F2-9B4F-0C10-D50A7A27F461> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
    0x7fff83998000 -     0x7fff839c9fff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <562565E1-AA65-FE96-13FF-437410C886D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff83b5a000 -     0x7fff84554ff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.8 (1038.36) <4CFBE04C-8FB3-B0EA-8DDB-7E7D10E9D251> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff84555000 -     0x7fff845e5fff  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <4175DC31-1506-228A-08FD-C704AC9DF642> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff845e6000 -     0x7fff8466bff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <CDFE82DD-D811-A091-179F-6E76069B432D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff84725000 -     0x7fff847a4fe7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <79E256EB-43F1-C7AA-6436-124A4FFB02D0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff847a5000 -     0x7fff84805fe7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <4F071EF0-8260-01E9-C641-830E582FA416> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff84806000 -     0x7fff84813fe7  libCSync.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <1C35FA50-9C70-48DC-9E8D-2054F7A266B1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
    0x7fff84814000 -     0x7fff8482afef  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <42D3023A-A1F7-4121-6417-FCC6B51B3E90> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff84898000 -     0x7fff84932fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 275.19 (???) <2DE8987F-4563-4D8E-45C3-2F6F786E120D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff8498d000 -     0x7fff84a4afff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359.2 (359.2) <BBB8888E-18DE-5D09-3C3A-F4C029EC7886> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff84a67000 -     0x7fff84b9cfff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <F4814A13-E557-59AF-30FF-E62929367933> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff84b9d000 -     0x7fff84bbefe7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <14F055F9-D7B2-27B2-E2CF-F0A222BFF14D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
    0x7fff84bbf000 -     0x7fff84bbfff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <2BB7D669-4B40-6A52-ADBD-DA4DB3BC0B1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff84bd4000 -     0x7fff84c3efe7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <75A8D840-4ACE-6560-0889-2AFB6BE08E59> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff84c3f000 -     0x7fff85086fef  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle 3.7.1 (570) <5AFA87CA-DC3D-F84E-7EA1-6EABA8807766> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
    0x7fff8527c000 -     0x7fff8529cfff  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.15) <9AD2A133-4275-5666-CE69-98FDF9A38B7A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
    0x7fff852e7000 -     0x7fff853a0fff  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <2C5ED312-E646-9ADE-73A9-6199A2A43150> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff856cd000 -     0x7fff8588bfff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0B4ABA92-C1F0-4548-A157-0CFD65561DA5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff858c6000 -     0x7fff858f1ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <3630A97F-55C1-3F34-CA63-3847653C9645> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff858f2000 -     0x7fff85925ff7  libTrueTypeScaler.dylib ??? (???) <B7BA8104-FA18-39A2-56E1-922EE7A660AC> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTrueTypeScaler.dylib
    0x7fff859ac000 -     0x7fff85c2efff  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.8 (751.63) <E10E4DB4-9D5E-54A8-3FB6-2A82426066E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff85fe6000 -     0x7fff8600efff  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <E9269069-93FA-2B71-F9BA-FDDD23C4A65E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff8600f000 -     0x7fff860c5ff7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <03140531-3B2D-1EBA-DA7F-E12CC8F63969> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff860c6000 -     0x7fff860d1ff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <F0DDF27E-DB55-07CE-E548-C62095BE8167> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff860d2000 -     0x7fff86150ff7  com.apple.CoreText 151.13 (???) <5C6214AD-D683-80A8-86EB-328C99B75322> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff861c6000 -     0x7fff862abfef  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11 (1.5.11) <39FAA3D2-6863-B5AB-AED9-92D878EA2438> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
    0x7fff862ac000 -     0x7fff862efff7  libRIP.A.dylib 545.0.0 (compatibility 64.0.0) <5FF3D7FD-84D8-C5FA-D640-90BB82EC651D> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
    0x7fff863a6000 -     0x7fff863adfff  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <4200CFB0-DBA1-62B8-7C7C-91446D89551F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff86564000 -     0x7fff86641fff  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <C3F44AA9-6F71-0684-2686-D3BBC903F020> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff86642000 -     0x7fff86758ff7  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <3814FCF9-92B9-A6AB-E76A-F7021894AA3F> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff867a5000 -     0x7fff867bbfe7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11) <8233CE71-6F8D-8B3C-A0E1-E123F6406163> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
    0x7fff867be000 -     0x7fff86808ff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <DE238BE4-5E22-C4D5-CF5C-3D50FDEE4701> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff86809000 -     0x7fff869c8fff  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.6 (3.0.6) <2C39859A-043D-0EB0-D412-EC2B5714B869> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff869c9000 -     0x7fff86a0afff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.8 (1.10.2) <78D48D27-A9C4-62CA-2803-D0BBED82855A> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff86ae6000 -     0x7fff86b0bff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <E138C8E7-3CB6-55A9-0A2C-B73FE63EA288> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff86b3c000 -     0x7fff86b3efff  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <61631C08-60CC-D122-4832-EA59824E0025> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
    0x7fff86bcd000 -     0x7fff86bdbff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <8145A534-95CC-9F3C-B78B-AC9898F38C6F> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff86bdc000 -     0x7fff86bebfef  com.apple.opengl 1.6.14 (1.6.14) <ECAE2D12-5BE3-46E7-6EE5-563B80B32A3E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff86c5e000 -     0x7fff86d13fe7  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <FFC46EE0-3544-A459-2AB9-94778A75E3D4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fff86d14000 -     0x7fff86d63ff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1) <01B370FB-D524-F660-3826-E85B7F0D85CD> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
    0x7fff86d64000 -     0x7fff86d9ffff  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <208DF391-4DE6-81ED-C697-14A2930D1BC6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff86da0000 -     0x7fff86db1ff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FB5EE53A-0534-0FFA-B2ED-486609433717> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff86db2000 -     0x7fff86df9ff7  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <D7645B59-0431-6283-7322-957D944DAB21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff86dfa000 -     0x7fff87604fe7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <FC941ECB-71D0-FAE3-DCBF-C5A619E594B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff87605000 -     0x7fff87605ff7  com.apple.Cocoa 6.6 (???) <68B0BE46-6E24-C96F-B341-054CF9E8F3B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff87606000 -     0x7fff8765bff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <F09541B6-5E28-1C01-C1AE-F6A2508670C7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
    0x7fff8765c000 -     0x7fff87a9ffef  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <0CC61C98-FF51-67B3-F3D8-C5E430C201A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff87aa0000 -     0x7fff87aa6ff7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1) <3691E9BA-BCF4-98C7-EFEC-78DA6825004E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
    0x7fff87ab5000 -     0x7fff87ab8ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <75819794-3B7A-8944-D004-7EA6DD7CE836> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff87ecd000 -     0x7fff87f07fff  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <4F2A4397-89BD-DEAC-4971-EE838FFA0964> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff87f21000 -     0x7fff87fe3fe7  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <EF06F16C-0CC9-B4CA-7BD9-0A97FA967340> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff8816b000 -     0x7fff8816bff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <DC7400FB-851E-7B8A-5BF6-6F50094302FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff8816c000 -     0x7fff8846afff  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???) <AD1C18F6-51CB-7E39-35DD-F16B1EB978A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff894d2000 -     0x7fff89593fef  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.8 (4.6.8) <7DF1D175-6451-51A2-DBBF-40FCA78C0D2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff897b8000 -     0x7fff897b9ff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <74800EE8-C14C-18C9-C208-20BBDB982D40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff897ba000 -     0x7fff897baff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <08D3D45D-908B-B86A-00BA-0F978D2702A7> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff8980b000 -     0x7fff89811ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <857F6E43-1EF4-7D53-351B-10DE0A8F992A> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff89812000 -     0x7fff89865ff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???) <F6E0C7A7-C11D-0096-4DDA-2C77793AA6CD> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff8988d000 -     0x7fff89bc1fef  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.39 (861.39) <1386A24D-DD15-5903-057E-4A224FAF580B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff89bec000 -     0x7fff89bf0ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <95718673-FEEE-B6ED-B127-BCDBDB60D4E5> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff89bfa000 -     0x7fff89c0efff  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <2ECE3B0F-39E1-3938-BF27-7205C6D0358B> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff89c0f000 -     0x7fff89c50fef  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <5DC41E81-32C9-65B2-5528-B33E934D5BB4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fff89c51000 -     0x7fff8a34dff7  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <58D597B1-EB3B-710E-0B8C-EC114D54E11B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff8a34e000 -     0x7fff8a354ff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <04EDCEDE-E36F-15F8-DC67-E61E149D2C9A> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff8a604000 -     0x7fff8a62bff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <472D4A31-C1F3-57FD-6453-6621C48B95BF> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff8a62c000 -     0x7fff8a641ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <DC999B32-BF41-94C8-0583-27D9AB463E8B> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff8a6c9000 -     0x7fff8a6caff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <49B723D1-85F8-F86C-2331-F586C56D68AF> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff8a764000 -     0x7fff8a7acff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <170DE04F-89AB-E295-0880-D69CAFBD7979> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <9AB4F1D1-89DC-0E8A-DC8E-A4FE4D69DB69> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Model: iMac5,1, BootROM IM51.0090.B09, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.16 GHz, 2 GB, SMC 1.9f4
Graphics: ATI Radeon X1600, ATY,RadeonX1600, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x87), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.42.4)
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Built-in Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST3250824AS  Q, 232.89 GB
Parallel ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-85J
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8501, 0xfd400000 / 2
USB Device: Dell USB Optical Mouse, 0x413c  (Dell Inc.), 0x3012, 0x1d100000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8206, 0x7d100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8240, 0x7d200000 / 3
```

Please, help! :-)

---

**HINT :** (if it matters at all) `[self thePanel]` (the window on which the `NSOpenPanel` appears as an alert sheet) is a HUD window, and not a "regular" one.

Comment: Hello, I too facing same issue, can you please throw any light how it got fixed, In my case, if i build a App from Xcode 4.5 on OSX 10.8 its crashing with the same call stack on 10.6.8

Comment: @Rohan Well, this how I *"fixed"* it : just compile it on 10.6.8. Sounds crazy? Well, maybe... But it sure did work. :-)

Comment: yes, but i have Xcode 3.2 on 10.6 , you mean download Xcode 4.X on 10.6 and then compile or downgrade entire project from 4.0 to 3.XYZ for 10.6

Comment: @Rohan Well, I'm not a guru on the subject and haven't actually figured out *what* was *really* going wrong. So, all I can say is what worked for me : and that was to recompile under 10.6.8 and Xcode 4.2 (Build 4C199 - just verified it). So why don't you try that? Getting the time to just download 4.2 for 10.6.8 might (just might) save you much more time... (Of course, I didn't mean to rewrite your entire project from scratch...)

Comment: thanks Dr. :) Can i install Xcode 4.2 over OSX 10.6. ?

Comment: @Rohan Coincidentally, I once had the same question. And guess what : someone on the Apple side of StackExchange did enlighten me... So, here you are... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45651/xcode-4-and-snow-leopard Good luck! :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22975/discussion-between-rohan-and-dr-kameleon)

Comment: The following may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560321/exc-bad-access-invoking-a-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me, for some still unknown reason, is to **compile the original source under 10.6.8** (with the already existing Xcode version, there - I'm not sure what that might have been, but most likely it's 4.2).

So, even if it sounds somewhat weird, it did the trick! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem. In my case, the culprit was [openPanel close]. The panel was getting over-released. I too had no problems in Snow Leopard, but it went bad as soon as I ported to Mavericks. Try commenting out [openPanel close] and see if that helps. Incidentally, the close function didn't seem to work anyway. Not sure what that's about. Maybe because it has already been dereferenced?

Comment: I think you're probably right. If you're looking for some corroboration from Apple, listing 5-1 from [Opening User Documents That You Plan to Display in a New Window](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH4-SW4) doesn't call `close`. (Ditto the other listings.)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the panel closing anyway? That makes the calling of `[openPanel close];` unnecessary.

```
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000030
```

Sounds like a Zombie.
Also, you should really switch to ARC